# Auto-Increment custom field in string which i can reset monthly

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way to make auto-increment column with characters in postgres eg: "**20171015aaaa**". Then i want to reset last characters on the bases of daily/monthly/yearly.If There is any references please share.

Comment: yes, there is a way to do anything you can describe in words

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please ask your question in a way that is clear, complete, and reproducible. See [how to do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For example, when you auto-increment the field, what will the next string look like? Are you trying to do this with a Rails callback? Do you need the database to handle it? What does the model look like? What code have you written in an attempt to solve the problem?